# Secrets Manager resource policy: "This resource policy contains a syntax error"

Tags: amazon-web-services, secretsmanager

I want to add Resource Permissions on my Secrets Manager secret and I have this syntax error:

```
This resource policy contains a syntax error
```

Can anyone help me? This is the policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "secretsmanager.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
            "Resource": "..."
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: this is what i did: {
    "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "secretsmanager.amazonaws.com"
                },
            "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
            "Resource": ""
    }]
}

Comment: Resource can't be `"..."`. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I presume you are wanting to enable automatic rotation of a Secrets Manager key? It appears that your policy is coming from [Permissions Required to Automatically Rotate Secrets - AWS Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/rotating-secrets-required-permissions.html). The wording on this page is not great -- this policy should actually be assigned to the IAM Role that will be used by the AWS Lambda function, whereas you are attempting to use it as a Resource Policy on the Secret itself. That's why it isn't working.

Comment: yes i use the arn of my resource i didn't put "..."

Comment: actually yes i want to enable automatic rotation of my secret in Secrets Manager, via lambda function. It's my first time and i have the python code that generate secret and modify secret value in secrets manager but i don't know haw to transform it to lambda function. please can you give me syntax of lambda function and the role i need to use to be able to do what i want, thank you for your help